# Unable to sync backbone js collection fetch data

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-views

Unable to sync the collection fetch data to local data.
Below is the code

The below code successfully fetching the data from the server and rendering to the view. But when i adding new element to the collection it not appending to server data, it creating new collection and adding to that one. How should i append new data to the existing server data.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>TODO supply a title</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <div>Tag List</div>

  <div id="tagTab">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    <button id="addTag"> Add</button>

    <ul id="tagList">
    </ul>

  </div>

  <script type="text/template" id="tag-name-template">

    <li>
      <%= title %>
    </li>
  </script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>



  <script>
    var app = {};

    var tagModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
      defaults: {
        title: 'mak',
        status: false
      },

      initialize: function() {

      }
    });

    var tagCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
      model: tagModel,
      initialize: function() {
        //                    console.log("collection added creation");
        //                    this.fetch();
      },
      url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
      parse: function(response) {
        //                console.log(response);
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; ++i) {
          //                               s console.log();
          this.add(response[i]);
          //                            this.add(new tagModel({title:response[i].title}));
        }

      }
    });


    var tagNameView = Backbone.View.extend({
      template: _.template($('#tag-name-template').html()),

      initialize: function() {
        this.render();
      },
      render: function() {

        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));

        return this;
        //                    return this.template(this.mode);
      }
    });

    var tagTabView = Backbone.View.extend({
      el: $('#tagTab'),
      model: new tagCollection(),

      initialize: function() {
        this.render();
        this.model.on('add', this.render, this);

        this.model.fetch();
      },
      render: function() {


        this.$('#tagList').html(''); // clean the todo list
        //                    console.log(this.model);
        for (var i = 0; i < this.model.length; ++i) {
          //                        console.log(this.model.at(i));
          this.$('#tagList').append(new tagNameView({
            model: this.model.at(i)
          }).el);
        }

      },
      events: {
        'click #addTag': 'add'


      },
      //To add the item to collections
      add: function() {


        // this.model.add(new tagModel({title:$("#name").val()}));
        this.model.add({
          title: $("#name").val()
        });
        $("#name").val("");
      }

    });
    app.view = new tagTabView();
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

.....

Comment: " it creating new collection and adding to that one" I don't see any code that would do this, do you mean you want to avoid a full re-render of the `<ul>` ? It'd be helpful to understand if you create a runnable stack snippet in the question

Comment: Hi, when you run the code snippet. it will show the list of data. when ever user add new tag data by clicking on the add button. It not appending to the Initial data.